# How to do a double sum in MATLAB given the explicit values of the function

Tags: summation, matlab

I have a double summation which I am trying to compute as follows

$$\sum_i^3\sum_j^3 h_{i,j} w_{i,j}$$

which I am trying to implement in MATLAB.. My application gives me the explicit values of both $h_{i,j} $ and $w_{i,j}$ and gives them as vector such as

For example $${\bf h} = [ h_{11}\,\, h_{12}\,\, h_{13} \,\,h_{21}\,\, h_{22}\,\, h_{23} ]^T$$
$${\bf w} = [ w_{11}\,\, w_{12}\,\, w_{13} \,\,w_{21}\,\, w_{22}\,\, w_{23} ]^T$$

where $T$ means transpose.
In order to find the double summation, I do the following in MATLAB

```
   for l =1: 6 
    v(i)=  h(i)*w(i)
  end 

for i = 1:6 
summation = sum_initial+ v(i)
end
```

Am I doing things correctly here?

Thanks,

Comment: Try this:
$sum(sum(h\cdot w^T))$

Comment: thank you, is it effectively doing the same thing?

Comment: Surely this is just `h'*w`? There is no double summation as far as I can tell, if $h,w$ are given as above.

Comment: thanks, so the code I present makes sense?, although I think it could be optimized//

Comment: @Henry: Well, your code is slower, uses more space and is much harder to read than `h'*w`.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, you are right. I falsely took h and w as 3x2 matrices

Comment: @Henry Yes, your code is correct. However, it is highly inefficient. But since you only have 6 elements in your array, it does not matter. As copper.hat wrote,  $h'\cdot w$ does the same job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you defined your vectors as two rows, then

just $h.'*w$ or if $h$ is real then $h'*w$ enough, this is a row vector times column vector, i.e. a dot\inner product

however, if you want them to be matrices (as it looks from your mathematical definition), then $h(:).'*w(:)$ will do the trick.

Your code could work if you fix it as following

```
for l =1: 6 
   v(i)=  h(i)*w(i);
end 

summation=0;
for i = 1:6 
   summation = summation + v(i);
end
```

Comment: +1: Cute trick using the : as a means of 'vectorising' a matrix.

Comment: Thank you, what did you fix with my code?

Comment: note the initialization of summation=0, removing sum_initial, and finaly using summation instead of  sum_initial. In your code you do not accumulate it, but change the value of summation each iteration, so that at the end you will get  summation = sum_initial+v(6) instead of what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming h and w are 3x3 matrices:

> h(:).'*w(:)

Comment: what version of Matlab has this VEC function? I never heard about that one.

Comment: Maybe it does not have it and it was just in my path for so long I had taken it for granted.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for something like the **bsxfun** function, which performas a binary operation, such as addition or multiplication, element-wise on two arrays:

```
summation = sum( bsxfun(@times, h, w) )
```